# Integrating tan functions

Tags: integration, trigonometry

Could someone please explain why the following is true:

$$\int_0^{\pi/4} \tan^{2n}x \, dx = \int_0^{\pi/4-\varepsilon} \tan^{2n} x \, dx + \int_0^{\pi/4-\varepsilon} \tan^{2n} x\,dx \text{?} $$ How is that possible, 2 almost-entire surfaces equal to 1 entire surface?

And this :

$$ \int_0^{\pi/4-\epsilon} \tan(\pi/4 -\varepsilon)x\,dx +\int_{\pi/4-\varepsilon}^{\pi/4} dx = (\tan^{2n}(\pi/4 -\varepsilon))\int_0^{\pi/4-\varepsilon} dx+\varepsilon\text{ ?}$$

EDIT: integrated variables missing
https://ibb.co/hzy98F picture

Comment: Why do you think this is true?

Comment: Your integrands are missing variables.  Do you mean $\tan^{2n} x$?

Comment: @MatthewConroy Yes, that's what I meant. I think it is true because this is the "answer" from my teacher regarding our homework

Comment: The best thing to do, then, would be to discuss this with your teacher.  Cheers!

Answer (score 2):

I think it's a typo; what was intended was this:
$$
\int_0^{\pi/4} \tan^{2n}x \, dx = \int_0^{\pi/4-\varepsilon} \tan^{2n} x \, dx + \int_{\pi/4-\varepsilon}^{\pi/4} \tan^{2n} x\,dx.
$$